# RedirectToAction in same controller not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

So I'm trying to use `RedirectToAction()` to redirect to another action in the same controller. However, everything that I have tried has not worked. Ideally I want to be able to type the link `/projects/assign/2`  and be redirected to the `/projects/create` page.
Examples of what I have tried:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Assign(int? id)
{
    return View("Create", id);
}
```

And:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Assign(int? id)
{
    return View("Create");
}
```

When I type `/projects/assign/2` in the address bar, I receive an error that says:

> "This page isn't working. If the problem continues, contact the site
> owner."

At this point, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and how to make it work.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Is the `projects` your controller name?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry I did not mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the following `Route` attributes:

```
[Route("Create/{id:int?}")]      
[Route("Assign/{id:int?}")] 

public IActionResult Create(int? id)
{
   ...
}
```

For more information see [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#rtp)

Answer (score 1):

just fix the action route

```
[HttpGet("{id?}")]
public IActionResult Assign(int? id)
{
    return View("Create", id);
}
```